# Error Boundry not catching some errors in NextJS

Tags: reactjs, error-handling, next.js, react-error-boundary

I'm trying to add a ErrorBoundry component to my NextJS project called ErrorShield

ErrorShield:

```
import { Component, useState } from "react";

export class Catch extends Component {
    componentDidCatch(error, info) {
        const { component } = this.props;
        this.props.setErrorInfo({
            hasError: true,
            error,
            info,
            component,
        });
    }
    render() {
        const { hasError, children, errorMessage } = this.props;
        if (hasError) errorMessage();
        return hasError ? null : children;
    }
}

const ErrorShield = (props) => {
    const { children } = props;
    const [errorInfo, setErrorInfo] = useState({
        component: "",
        error: null,
        info: null,
        hasError: false,
    });

    const errorMessage = () => {
        if (errorInfo.hasError) {
            console.groupCollapsed(
                `%c ⛔ Error in the component: ${errorInfo.component} `,
                "color:#ff3333;",
            );
            console.groupCollapsed("%c  Props:", "color:#039BE5;");
            console.table(children.props);
            console.groupEnd();
            console.groupCollapsed("%c  Error:", "color:#F44336;");
            console.log(errorInfo.error);
            console.groupEnd();
            console.groupEnd();
        }
    };
    return (
        <Catch
            {...props}
            hasError={errorInfo.hasError}
            errorMessage={errorMessage}
            setErrorInfo={setErrorInfo}
        />
    );
};

export default ErrorShield;
```

At first it was working as intended but I notices that sometimes if I break some components the ErrorShield won`t catch the error, I tried to see if the behavior had any consistency but I cant find it.

For example, my project has a Header like this:

```
const Header = (props) => {
    const { navigation } = props;
    const [titles, setTitles] = useState(navigation);

    .....

    {/*HeaderLinkContainer, HeaderLinkBox, HeaderLiveLink and HeaderSubLink are styled components*/}
    <HeaderLinkContainer variant="Transparent" as="nav">
        <HeaderLinkBox variant="Transparent">
            {titles.map((title) => {
                let LinkTag;
                if (title.live) {
                    LinkTag = HeaderLiveLink;
                } else if (title.subnav) {
                    LinkTag = HeaderSubLink;
                } else {
                    LinkTag = HeaderLink;
                }

                return (
                    <LinkTag
                        href={title.path}
                        key={title.name}
                        active={SECTION[0] === title.path}
                    >
                        {title.name}
                    </LinkTag>
                );
            })}
        </HeaderLinkBox>
    </HeaderLinkContainer>
```

And I call that component in the layout:

```
<ErrorShield component="layout/LayoutResponsive -> Header">
    <Header
        breadcrumbs={breadcrumbs}
        social={social}
        viewTickerAmp={viewTickerAmp}
    />
</ErrorShield>
```

If I break this component by changing this:

```
{titles.map((title) => {
```

into this:

```
{/*Added an extra t*/}
{titles.map((ttitle) => {
```

The ErrorShield does work as intended, it renders nothing and prints this on the console:

[image: ErrorShieldWorking]

However if I break it like this:

```
{/*Added an extra t at the beginning*/}
{ttitles.map((title) => {
```

It does not catch the error and I get this message in the console:

[image: ErrorShieldNotWorking]

I have another component named ContentCarrusel with a similar .map() in it but the ErrorShield does work in it without problems:

```
{/*ContentCarouselStyles, ContentCarouselTitleStyles, ContentCarouselThumbStyles are styled components */}
{/*ItemCarousel is a child component*/}

<ContentCarouselStyles>
    <ContentCarouselTitleStyles variant="h3">Para Ti</ContentCarouselTitleStyles>
    {items.map((item, index) => {
        return (
            <ContentCarouselThumbStyles key={item.key}>
                <ItemCarousel {...item} isAmp={isAmp} />
            </ContentCarouselThumbStyles>
        );
    })}
</ContentCarouselStyles>
```

Here it doesn't matter if I break it like this:

```
{iitems.map((item, index) => {
```

or this:

```
{items.map((iitem, index) => {
```

The ErrorShield still catches the error and works as intended.

I have a lot more of examples of inconsistent behavior if you need them, also let me know if you need more info. Thank you